# Displaying live image from camera

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing

I am developing a C# .NET application which will display the image captured from a camera (smart camera). I am using the function below to convert the raw data received from the camera (which is a byte array) to a bitmap image. The problem I face with the below code is that, the image displayed in the C# .NET application's picture box (which should be a live image ideally) looks like a movie reel and it keeps scrolling to the right. Any idea how to solve this issue?

```
private Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] myByteArray) 
{
    if (myByteArray != null)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(myByteArray);
        int Height = 504; /*The exact height of image from Smart Camera*/
        int Width = 664;  /*The exact width of image from Smart Camera*/

        BitmapData bmpData = 
            bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), 
                         ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);

        Marshal.Copy(myByteArray, 0, bmpData.Scan0, myByteArray.Length);

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Width, Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        BitmapData bmpData = 
            bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), 
                         ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);
        int offset = 0;
        long ptr = bmpData.Scan0.ToInt64();
        for (int i = 0; i < Height; i++)
        {
            Marshal.Copy(myByteArray, offset, new IntPtr(ptr), Width);
            offset += (Width);
            ptr += bmpData.Stride;
        }
        bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
        return bmp;
    }
    return null;
}
```

@Mark, find below the code segment i use for receiving data from camera ...

Logic : I receive the sizeof image first and then open socket connection n loop till i get the sizeof bytes from the camera.

```
public static byte[] receivedata(Socket clientSock)
{
    if (clientSock != null)
    {
        byte[] size = new byte[10000000]; 
        byte[] buffer = null;
        int ch, received, offset;

        try
        {
            clientSock.Receive(size);
            //MessageBox.Show("size array is " + size[0] 
            // +  " " + size[1] +  " " + size[2] +  " " );
            ch = BitConverter.ToInt32(size, 0);

            //ch = 334656;

            //MessageBox.Show("Sizeofimg = " + ch + "");

            buffer = new byte[ch];

            //MessageBox.Show("Start receiving image from camera");
            received = 0;
            offset = 0;
            do
            {
                received += clientSock.Receive(buffer, 
                                               offset + received, 
                                               ch - received,
                                               SocketFlags.None);
            } while (received < ch);

                //MessageBox.Show("Received " + received + " values");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error receiving ...");
                MessageBox.Show(e.StackTrace);
            }
            return buffer;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Kindly point out the problem ... 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help to know the model of the camera.

Comment: P.S. As much as I like seeing my name in lights, you'll have better luck not trying to page me specifically.

Answer (score 0):

"Scrolling to the right" tells me that each image is decoding consistently, but successive images are off in relation to one another.  Correct?  That means the problem is not in the code you've shown us, but in the code that reads from the camera.

**Edit:** it seems likely that your width and height are off by a little bit. The only documentation I've found for a 664x504 camera states that the "active area" (the part that actually contains a picture) is really 648x488. If this is the case, your picture would also seem to slant a little as each line would be offset from the next, and would shift up as  each frame you read would get part of the next frame's data.

Comment: @Mark, find my reply in the edited section of my original post. Kindly help.